# How to add unused partition of the first disk to /home in the second disk

Tags: partitioning, disk, gparted

I have two ssd disks, Disk B is devoted to /home, and disk A is the filesystem and is 90% empty.

So I made on disk A a partition /dev/sda3 with 80% of the free space. Now I am wondering what is the best way to somehow add the newly created partition to my /home which is located at /dev/sdb1?

Comment: Um, I'm gonna have to say that your question is quite unclear.. Please clarify it!! :)

Comment: Well, it may be open ended, since I am open to different suggestions, but unclear, I don't reckon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line in **/etc/fstab** for that disk and it will be mounted automatically i.e.

```
/dev/sdXY /mnt/data   ext4 noatime,noexec
```

You can mount it somewhere else and create a soft link to a folder under your home with big files (say downloads or something) and spread the files between the two

```
ln -s /mnt/data /home/alifish/downloads
```

with

```
df /home/alifish/downloads
```

you should see the true location of the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can't make /home point to 2 drives/partitions. What you could do, however, is move your largest /home subfolder to /dev/sda3, then mount that under /home.

Comment: Well, the problem is that actual /home is 120GB but the restored space is 80GB. I tried to chown the new partition to my user to use it as an extra partition available but each time it needs root password to open the partition. It is a rather dirty solution, so I hoped there is a better one.

Comment: add a line in /etc/fstab for that disk and will be mounted automatically. You can mount it somewhere else and create a soft link to a folder under your home with big files (say downloads or something) and spread the files between the two

Comment: jet, would you elaborate on the solution as a separate answer please. I'll choose it as it sounds quite good.